# Log File Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Newbie here. I would like to ask for a help in creating a basic log file on what values inserted on the field.

Here's my html:

```
<form id = "form1" name = "form1" method="post">
<div id="fstep_1">
    <p>
         Your email address:
    </p>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email">
    <label for="email" class="error" style="display: none;">This field is required</label>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="fsubmit">Submit</button>
```

here's my jquery:

```
<script>
$(".fsubmit").click(function() {    
        var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/logfiletracker.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'data' : {email: emailval,
            success: function(data) {},
        });
  });
</script>
```

Here's my ajax:

```
<script>
$(".fsubmit").click(function() {    
        var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/logfiletracker.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'data' : {email: emailval,
            success: function(data) {},
        });
  });
</script>
```

Here's my PHP

```
<?php 

$data = $_POST['data'];
$date = new DateTime();
$datelog = $date->format('d.m.Y h:i:s');


$message = '[' . $datelog . '] - email: ' .$data;

echo($message);
?>
```

My problem is that it doesn't view any data at all except the date which is looks like this one

```
[02.02.2017 12:54:11] - email:
```

And when I tried to add another test, it doesn't increment the data. Is there something lack in my code?

Your answers are appreciated.

Comment: `$message = '[' . $datelog . '] - email: ' . json_encode($data);`? [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @json_encode the output is [02.02.2017 01:41:08] - email: null

Comment: syntax error? maybe `data: { 'data' : { email: emailval } },`

Comment: @ramabarca same output. email: null

Answer (score 1):

for testing purposes, to know where the problem is (js or php), you can do:

On *JavaScript*:

```js
$(".fsubmit").click(function() {    
    var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();
    var data = {
        'data' : {
            email: emailval
        }
    };

    // testing!
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/logfiletracker.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {}
    });
});
```

On *PHP*:

```php
<?php 

$data = $_POST['data'];

// testing!
echo json_encode($_POST['data']);
exit;

$date = new DateTime();
$datelog = $date->format('d.m.Y h:i:s');


$message = '[' . $datelog . '] - email: ' .$data;

echo($message);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/logfiletracker.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'data' : emailval},
        success: function(data) {},
   });
```

Because your data is not being sent in a proper manner and is not received by php. Modify your Ajax code and it will work